# Simple Java based Spark program doesn't get Finished

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I created a very simple "Word count" Java based Spark program, and I am running it in a cluster running on YARN with the below details:

## Hadoop details:

Master Node (NN, SNN, RM) - 192.168.0.100
Slave  Nodes (DN, NM) - 192.168.0.105, 192.168.0.108

## Spark details:

Master running on : 192.168.0.100
Workers running on : 192.168.0.105, 192.168.0.108

I have created a client machine from where I submit the Spark job (The IP address of client machine is --> 192.168.0.240).

## The below command I used to submit the Job to Spark:

```
spark-submit --class com.example.WordCountTask --master yarn /root/SparkCodeInJava/word-count/target/word-count-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /spark/input/inputText.txt /spark/output
```

However the program doesn't terminate at all, the data-set is very small (10 text lines) and I expect it to finis without taking much time.

The below is the output I see on console after submitting the Job:

```
17/03/26 19:54:42 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1490572543329_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/03/26 19:54:43 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1490572543329_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/03/26 19:54:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1490572543329_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/03/26 19:54:45 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1490572543329_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/03/26 19:54:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1490572543329_0001 (state: ACCEPTED)
```

And this continues forever. I am not sure why this isn't getting completed.

This is what I see in GUI for this application:

[image]

## The below is the output of: yarn logs -applicationId application_1490572543329_0002

```
17/03/26 20:24:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop libra
/tmp/logs/root/logs/application_1490572543329_0002 does not exist.
```

Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.

This is my first Spark program, and I configured to run it on YARN cluster.

I simulate the distributed environment using 4 VM's , Cent OS running on Virtualbox.

Can anyone help me why this program isn't functioning properly?

## Update:

I set up the environment in AWS , with two launched instance with good configuration (8 Vcpu's and 32 GB RAM), but the job isn't still getting completed.

## (A) yarn-site.xml

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>ip-XXX-YYYY-ZZZ-AAA.us-west-2.compute.internal:8032</value>
    </property>
```

## (B) After submitting the Job using spark-submit, I see this in the output which is displayed on console:

```
17/03/29 15:51:35 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with **0 NodeManagers**
```

Has this to do anything with the Job not getting finished?

Comment: What does `yarn logs -applicationId application_1490572543329_0001` show? What do you see in YARN UI at 8888 re this app?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: I have added the screen shot what I see in YARN UI.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: I have added the log details.

Comment: @franklinsijo: I did that as well, but still it is not able to finish.

Comment: Can you add your `yarn-site.xml`!

Comment: @franklinsijo File added

Comment: @franklinsijo: I corrected the typo in yarn-site.xml, but it is still giving me the same behavior , that is program still runs.

Comment: @franklinsijo: I update one more log output in the update section, please have a look if that is causing the program to wait forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `ERROR` messages,

> YARN Application State: ACCEPTED, waiting for AM container to be
>   allocated

```
17/03/29 15:51:35 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with **0 NodeManagers**
```

YARN is unable to allocate containers for the Spark application as there are no active `NodeManager(s)` available.

Nodemanagers use the property `yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address` to communicate with `ResourceManager`. 
By default, the value of this property is set as

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
   <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8031</value>
</property>
```

The reference property `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname` defaults to `0.0.0.0`. Nodemanagers will not be able to communicate with the RM unless the RM hostname is defined properly.

Modify this property in `yarn-site.xml` for all the nodes

```
 <property>
   <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
   <value>rm_hostname</value> <!-- Hostname of the node where Resource Manager is started -->
</property>
```

Also, the property `yarn.nodemanager.auxservices` must be `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services`.

Restart the services after the changes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed information and guidance over chat, it really helped resolve the issue. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

If "ACCEPTED" status keeps continuing with out any "FAILED" status at any time it means the cluster resource allocation allows your job to be submitted but currently there is no free resource in order to launch your job in container. The state machine looks similar to [hadoop tasks'](http://ercoppa.github.io/HadoopInternals/Task.html)

Comment: Is this something related to my laptop's configurations? I am running all these nodes in my 4 different VM's , hosted in Virtualbox. It has 2 core, 4 virtual CPUs.

Comment: What is current VM configs and spark (executor and driver) configs due to submit ?

Comment: How to check that? I am submitting the job like this: spark-submit --class com.example.WordCountTask --master yarn /root/SparkCodeInJava/word-count/target/word-count-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /spark/input/inputText.txt /spark/output

Comment: spark-defaults.conf file check under your spark/conf

Comment: I checked it, there is no such file, there is file with name -> spark-defaults.conf.template